# How to convert a csv file into json in react native

Tags: json, react-native, csv

I want to convert a csv file into a json or an array of objects in react native. I know there are eternal libraries like Papa Parse for react, but I'm not sure if they work with React native. Is there any way to do this in react native?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/45057465/10718641

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)